# Adding new project to GIT source control from existing solution

Tags: git, github, version-control, visual-studio-2017

I have a solution in visual studio, which is in git source control.
I have now added another project to this solution and would like that to be part of the same git source.
However, where ever i search for this they say: File-menu > Add to source control.
The problem is, there is no such button when the solution is already under source control.

What to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Visual Studio, projects are part of a solution. If your solution is already under source control, each project under it should automatically be in source control as well when it's created.

Updated from comments: if your projects are in a different folder than your solution, you will need to manually add them to Git.

Comment: I would like to think so too, but its not. There is nothing to commit, and no way to add it. And it does not show up on my repo at github.com either

Comment: I just added another new test project to the solution, and nothing about it to commit, other than the solution file has changed of course

Comment: My other projects are not in the same folder, could that be a problem?

Comment: That sounds like it could be the problem - try adding the other folders to source control individually via the command line?

Comment: Yes, apparently git will not include projects not under the same folder as the repo folder. Working now, Thanks